# Docker blocking outgoing connections on high load?

Tags: sockets, http, tcp, docker, dokku

We have a node.js web server that makes some outgoing http requests to an external API. It's running in docker using [dokku](https://github.com/progrium/dokku).
After some time of load (30req/s) these outgoing requests aren't getting responses anymore.

Here's a graph I made while testing with constant req/s:
[image: graph]
`incoming` and `outgoing` is the amount of concurrent requests (not the number of initialized requests). (It's hard to see in the graph, but it's fairly constant at ~10 requests for each.)
`response time` is for external requests only.
You can clearly see that they start failing *all of a sudden* (hitting our 1000ms timeout).

---

The more req/s we send, the faster we run into this problem, so we must have some sort of limit we're getting closer to with each request.

---

I used `netstat -ant | tail -n +3 | wc -l` on the host to get the number of open connections, but it was only ~450 (most of them `TIME_WAIT`). That shouldn't hit the socket limit. We aren't hitting any RAM or CPU limits, either.

---

I also tried running the same app on the same machine outside docker and **it only happens in docker**.

Comment: Have you tried running it inside Docker but not inside Dokku?

Comment: Define 'currently processed'. 1000ms is far too short for a request timeout. Try something sensible like ten seconds.

Comment: @maybeg I haven't because the dokku guys told me they aren't touching any network things. I will try that later.

Comment: @EJP 1000ms is actually a lot for an external API request. The result isn't any different when I make it longer though. (And none of our users waits 10+ seconds for an HTTP request to finish)

Comment: @jomo Actually it isn't a lot. You're within range of theTCP retry timeouts. It's too short.

Comment: @jomo - Any info on running it without Dokku?  I'm working on a project using Docker now and would love to know if this is or isn't a docker issue.

Comment: Might be related to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840817/docker-container-http-requests-limit

Comment: @Regan We indeed have local connections to redis (running in another container). I was also suspecting that it might be causing the issue, but the problem in docker persisted after removing redis.

Answer (score 4):

It could be due to the Docker userland proxy.  If you are running a recent version of Docker, try running the daemon with the `--userland-proxy=false` option.  This will make Docker handle port forwarding with just iptables and there is less overhead.

Comment: I just tried this, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @jomo, in that case, it could be a kernel configuration.  Maybe this SO question/answer could give you something to look in to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410616/increasing-the-maximum-number-of-tcp-ip-connections-in-linux

Comment: that's what we initially thought was the problem, but it wouldn't explain why it doesn't happen outside docker (where we actually had more connections than in docker)

Comment: Your answer didn't really solve my problem, but I rather give the bounty to *someone* instead of letting it disappear forever. Have funs :)

Comment: @jomo can you post output of 'sysctl net' in the container and out of the container? I'm pretty sure the network namespace can have different sysctl parameters for network stuff.

Comment: @Mack [inside container](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=SS8EDSxT), [outside container](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=UBZQ7KJ2)

Comment: @jomo anything stick out in the logs or dmesg when the outbound connections start getting dropped?

Comment: @jomo I'm wondering if this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033631/node-js-maxing-out-at-1000-concurrent-connections

I'm starting to think it might be nodejs instead of Docker, but maybe something about Docker triggers it.

Comment: @MarkDuncan ulimit doesn't seem to be the issue, we tested that as well :|

Comment: @jomo I'm at a loss. If you figure this out please post solution. Best of luck.